# facebook api call from multiple pages

Tags: facebook

I'm creating a facebook app with facebook php adk 3.0.

I was able to do facebook connect login successfully as per the sample code from  github.
the page to which i'm redirecting after facebook login is returning my correct user id using the function
                 $user = $facebook->getUser();

But if i go to any other page in the app, and if i call $facebook->getUser();, it's returning zero.

Seems like i should save logged in user session some where, anybody know solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

After long search i found solution for this.

From the page to which u'll be redirected after facebook login, store access token in session.

```
                 $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
                 $_SESSION['token'] = $access_token;
```

Then if you want to call a fb api from any other page, set access token as below before calling the api.

```
            $access_token = $_SESSION['token'];
            $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
```

Hope it will help.